# How to force chrome and Firefox to resize in bluestack

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bluestacks

I installed Bluestack on my PC and I also success resized the inner window of the Bluestack which makes all apps resized to a normal android phone. But the issue is the Chrome and Firefox browsers refuse to be resized, they display in a tablet form.

Please do anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Bluestacks 2** you have a single button on **left hand side**, press that **after you have opened an app** to toggle the orientation.

[image]

for **Bluestacks 3**  you have to goto **Settings > Manage applications**  here you can select in between tablet or default

[image]

[image]